# How do I get my jquery post request to work with the variable stored from a function on a click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to pass a game's name through to my php function as soon as a user clicks a button.  The idea is the user clicks a button, which has a value of its videogame name, then the php script checks that game's ranking and returns that ranking to the html.  I have made post requests work before, and even here when I manually set the variable name to one of the Games to test it, it works.  Please help!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //global n variable
    n = $();

        $('#target').click(function(){
            //set value of n to the game's name
                n = $(this).val();

        });

        //then send the name as term to my php function to deal with it and return 
        //the ranking
    $.post('getTotal.php', {term: n}, function(data){
        //been trying to see if anything comes through for debugging purposes
                alert(data);

        //commented this out for now, just puts it in the div I left open
        //$('#total').html(data);
    });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply when the user clicks the button. inside the click handler, obtain the value and perform  an http post

$ajax or $POST

eg -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#target').click(function()
            $.ajax({  
              type: "POST",
              url: "url...",
              data: "n="+nVal+",
              success: function(html){
                alert( "Submitted");
              }
           });
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put the `$.post` into your click handler... so it will only run when you actually click the button... now your code sets up an `n` variable, its value is an empty jQuery object (why?). Then it attaches a click handler on the button. Then it runs a `$.post` request - `n` is still an empty jQuery object. Clicking the button happens much later...

Also, using globals should be avoided. The `var` keyword should be used when declaring variables.